# Logarithm in P-adic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

The following question was asked in a talk of P-adic numbers and I was not able to complete the proof of this result.

> Question :  Show that $log_p(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{ (x-1)^n } {n} $ for $x\in 1+ p\mathbb{Z}_p <=> |x-1|_p <1$.

Attempt:  I have proved that $log_p(a) $  converges for $|x-1|_p<1$ but I am not able to show how does $x\in 1+p\mathbb{Z}_p <=> |x-1|_p< 1$.

Edit 1 : I am not able to show how does the condition $|x-1|_p <1$  is equivalent to  $x\in 1+ p\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Please help me with this!

Comment: Can you clarify what is unclear to you? If $x\in \Bbb{Q}_p$ then the series for $\log_p(x)$ converges iff $x\in 1+p\Bbb{Z}_p$ iff $|x-1|_p < 1$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for comment. I have edited my question. I am not able to show how the condition $|x -1|_p <1$ is equivalent to the condition $ x\in 1+ p\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: That's immediate from the definition of the $p$-adic absolute value and of the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what your difficulty is. The value group is discrete, and there are no elements $z\in\Bbb Q_p$ with $|p|<|z|<1$.

Comment: Write `$\iff$` to get $\iff$. That $<=>$ is making the angels cry.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of $|y|_p$ for $y \in \mathbf Q_p$, we have (i) $y \in \mathbf Z_p \Longleftrightarrow |y|_p \leq 1$ and (ii) $y \in p\mathbf Z_p \Longleftrightarrow |y|_p \leq 1/p$.

Since no $p$-adic absolute value is strictly between $1/p$ and $1$, $|y|_p<1  \Longleftrightarrow |y|_p \leq 1/p$.  Thus $y \in p\mathbf Z_p \Longleftrightarrow |y|_p < 1$. Using $x-1$ for $y$, $|x-1|_p < 1 \Longleftrightarrow x-1 \in p\mathbf Z_p$, which is equivalent to $x \in 1 + p\mathbf Z_p$.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi what definition of $|y|_p$ have you ever seen?  For example, what do you consider to he $|p|_p$?